# Cannot send email from appfog using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail, appfog

This is my first time using appfog. I have a PHP application. I want to send email from the PHP application using appfog. I am using CodeIgniter framework.

I can send email from my localhost. But when I try to do the same thing using appfog I am getting error. It is saying that authentication has failed. My email sending PHP code is given below.

```
$config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'shamir.towsif@gmail.com',
                'smtp_pass' => 'xxxx',
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => true
            );
            $message = "Random message";
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('shamir.towsif@gmail.com', 'Vatiali');
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
            $this->email->subject('Verify Email');
            $this->email->message($message);
            $this->email->send();
```

Comment: I think if you are on a free account you don't have ssl access which means you can't log into the gmail smtp server.

Comment: BTW, I recently set up sendgrid to use on appfog. If you use composer to download sendgrid, that way you get all the dependencies, it isn't too bad. Plus they give you 200 free emails per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option could be to use AWS SNS to send your emails. Pretty easy to setup using the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-sns.html).
You also get 1000 free messages per month on the free tier.